# Maintaining a list of programs I don't want Make to compile that I could change with >> and SED instead of editing the makefile?

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I'm pretty new to Make.  My current Makefile is below.  It compiles all .c files into the respective executable file.  The list of c files is constantly growing (I'm adding more and more files, p1.c, p2.c, p3.c, ...).  So I want it to compile *most* of them, but if there's a particular file that has errors I don't want to bother with, I'd like to be able to put it on do-not-compile list--that is, instead of telling make what I *do* want to compile, it would be faster to tell it what I *don't* want to compile.  It would be easy to have a file say dont.txt that I add and remove lines to, each of which contain "px.c".  If I had such a file, how would I tell make *not* to compile those .c files?

```
CFLAGS = -g -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall

SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)

PROGS = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

all: $(PROGS)

%: %.c

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -o $@ $<
```

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter out source files which you do not want to compile like

```
SRCS = $(filter-out excludefile.c, $(wildcard *.c))
```

Also if you maintain files name which you want to exclude then use command as follows

for example file is `exclude.txt` then

```
EXCLUDES := $(shell cat ./exclude.txt)

SRCS = $(filter-out $(EXCLUDES), $(wildcard *.c))
```

Comment: @user3391564 yes you can.